# got Mail with more 'toaddress'. where to find?

Tags: php, parsing, email

I receive a Mail, whitch was send to more than one addresses.
All Adresses are on the same server.
The server ist configured for 'catch all'.

When I get the header (imap_headerinfo) or overview (imap_fetch_overview) there is only one 'toaddress'.

The 'to' array from  the header has also only one address.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [date] => Wed, 19 Feb 2014 15:53:05 +0100
    [Date] => Wed, 19 Feb 2014 15:53:05 +0100
    [subject] => hhhh
    [Subject] => hhhh
    [message_id] => 
    [toaddress] => test@domain.at
    [to] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [mailbox] => test
                    [host] => domain.at
                )

        )

    [fromaddress] => tester 
    [from] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [personal] => tester
                    [mailbox] => tester
                    [host] => gmx.at
                )
```

The webmailer shows me both adresses so the info, the secon address should be somewhere.

Where can I find this second 'to' address?

Thank you,
andi

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a parser doing the thing for me.

https://github.com/plancake/official-library-php-email-parser

Thank you,
andi

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using

```
$result = imap_fetch_overview($imap_conn,1,0);
```

bevor

```
$header=imap_headerinfo ( $imap_conn, $msg_nr);
```

couses this problem.